# How to add transactions to QB using ODBC from access

Tags: ms-access, transactions, odbc, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I know that transactions can be altered using ODBC in access/ excel and it works perfectly. How can I write a whole new transaction from MS access using ODBC.

I want add transactions to;

- Build Assembly
- List item

Inventory Adjustment

This seems accomplish-able if I can correctly add information to fields like "TxnID", "EditSquence"  etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QuickBooks Enterprise Solutions software comes with ODBC, but it is a read-only connection and does not support adding/updating. There is an addon software called QODBC that uses the QBSDK to support read/write ODBC access to the QuickBooks file in QuickBooks Enterprise, Premier, and Pro versions. You can find more information about the QODBC addon at http://www.qodbc.com/default.htm

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I'm using QODBC with linked table in Access 2013 but unable to add transactions as stated above with particular problems with non-familiar filed like TxnID etc. I know it is not going to work with linked tables bu please recommend solution for that.

Comment: If you are adding a new transaction, you don't need `TxnID` or `EditSequence` as they are generated by QuickBooks. There's a tutorial on the QODBC website that shows how to add an InventoryItem, which will be similar to any other type of Item that you want to add (ServiceItem, NonInventoryItem, DiscountItem, etc). Based on the information here http://www.qdeveloper.com.au/forum.php?homeinclude=topicdetails&forum_id=1&category_id=3&post_id=773 it may appear that BuildAssemblies can not be added by QODBC, though it is an older post.

Comment: OK I'll check this but what did you searched to digg the link out of internet :)

Comment: I just used Google to search for 'qodbc assembly'. Though, the thread does show updates that indicate that it should be possible using QODBC v7.00.00.194 or later. INSERT INTO BuildAssembly (ItemInventoryAssemblyRefFullName, RefNumber, QuantityToBuild)
VALUES ('Interior Door kit', 'QODBC1', 2)